# Eclipse does not read the correct context root of web modules values from EAR that is compiled with Maven when it published to WebSphere

Tags: eclipse, maven, websphere, ear

I have a Maven project that creates an ear file for WebSphere, and I can upload it to the WebSphere directly (From the webconsole), however- when I try to deploy it from Eclipse- The eclipse identifies both WAR files instances (One under the target of its module, and one under the target of the EAR module) and configures them as context root, instead of the definition in the application.xml

Any idea what can cause the Eclipse to do it?

Comment: One set of settings I know with some overlap here is [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHR6W/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/prefs.html) since I believe it configures the Java EE tooling with values aligned with the Maven defaults.    If that doesn't help, can you share a sample project maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to go to the server and in the installedApps folder and see what is there in extracted form. In the directory of your ear you will find some extra files that are generated by WebSphere during the manual deploy (and these files for some reason are not generated via Eclipse or maven deploy).

When I was in the same shoes I copied these files to the proper folders in the maven projects and checked when I am doing the deploy via maven, these WebSphere-generated xml files are placed correctly (to the same location as during the manual deploy).

The drawback of this that if you change something around your EJBs, around the security (so around the source data that WebSphere used when these extra files have been generated) you will have to keep these files in sync with the source data files (and of course, you have to understand the logic, but that will not be that hard).
(The other solution is from time to time do a manual deploy and simply write over the old files in your project. This is usually required when you add or remove annotated classes.)

What are these files?

**ear level**

- ibm-application-bnd.xml (application roles - real group mappings, this is important to have)

**war level**

- ibm-metadata.xml (the WAS scans the classpath and make this xml what classes are annotated, this is one of them that can cause your problem if I remember well)
- ibm-web-ext.xml (as the name suggests, some general settings, like jsp reload, directory browsing or file serving is enabled or not, etc.)
- ibm-datasource-ext.xml and ibm-web-bnd.xml (datasource related settings)
- ibm-managed-beans.xml and ibm-managed-bean-bnd.xml - I don't know, they were empty in my project

If you add these to your project, you will be able to deploy using maven, albeit I am not sure that will work with Eclipse as well.
We used [com.orctom.mojo:was-maven-plugin](https://github.com/orctom/was-maven-plugin) for the deployment.

Comment: The thing is- From the WebSphere admin console I can install the ear that was created by Maven successfully, only from the Eclipse when I try to add the EAR as resource, I see that it finds two war files, one with the location of the war module/target, and one under the target folder of the ear module,  In stead of having one war file in the context-root specified in the application.xml file

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Eclipse- Maven configuration was not set right.

1) The configuration phase should be done with Oracle JDK, and only later we should switch to IBM JDK for deployment
2) Once the Maven "Update project" was performed correctly, the deploy assembly of each module was set correctly in the properties of each module, and then I could continue to the deploy it in WebSphere, after the EAR add the correct war context-root